# MySQL - mysql database priviledges and root user

Tags: mysql

so..

I'm watching a Tutorial Video courtesy of Lynda.com on the basics of MySQL (cool Stuff),
The instructor is instructing us on setting up Root User Password via Console (which i've actually already Done).

He stated the following :

MySQL Stores it Users,Root Users and Permission for those users in a table called user, located in a datbase called mysql

Then a little lightbulb appeared above my head and i typed this in

{SHOW DATABASES;}

{USE mysql;}

{SHOW TABLES;}

{SELECT * FROM user;)

Then a bunch of stuff appeared that was obviously all the user info

so HERE'S MY QUESTION (actually 2 if i may)

1.Am i correct in assuming that if i (hypothetically) modify they "Y"'s or the "N"'s , i then effectively alter the permissions and/or access grants to those corresponding users.

LASTLY, i have set my password, and next to my name in the list, under the password column, there is a really long string of what appears to be a Hexadecimal string

Just for fun How would i convert that back so that it shows my password
(FYI I'm familiar with conversion of Binary to hex and to decimal and so on, but i'm guessing there's some sort of encryption at work here, perhaps AES or 3DES or something)

it's starts with a Star , followed by 40 Hex Characters,  my password is only 12 Characters Long

so..to finish up,  in doing all this, i now think i understand what the purpose of the mysql schema is in MYSQL

and needless to say i shouldn't delete it... right  LOL

all input on this subject is greatly appreciated ahead of time
thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am i correct in assuming that if i (hypothetically) modify they "Y"'s or the "N"'s , i then effectively alter the permissions and/or access grants to those corresponding users.

Yes - however the data is cached independently of the query cache - hence updating the table won't immediately give you this access - you need to reload the privileges or restart the database before the changes take effect.

> How would i convert that back so that it shows my password

You can't. It's a [cryptographic hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) of your password. However given enough time and enough computing resource you can find a string which results in the same hash (which might be the same as the pasword) - this could then be used to log in as that user. But we're talking about millions of CPU hours here.

Comment: Regarding the first bit, Yes, i know that, sorry forgot to mention it, i do know that after i edit all that i need to edit i need to {FLUSH PRIVILEGES}  not (FLUSH PRIVILEDGES}  i need to remember i'm in australia and MYSQL is an American Thing,  Regarding the password thing,  LOL, How Cool, Millions of CPU hours, i sort of gathered as much, I love code and i love understanding how it works,  anyway, thanks for all that, Learnt something new, I'll research Cryptographic Hash,  Appreciate it.. Be Cool

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can set 'Y' or 'N' in those rows, but after modifying system security tables you will have to execute `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` command. I'd suggest you to use [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) or [REVOKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/revoke.html) command instead of editing system tables directly.
2. No, it is not possible to decrypt MySQL user's password.

Comment: thankyou for that answer, i appreciate your suggestion regarding GRANT and REVOKE,  Of Course..I wouldn't edit the table directly, i was just speaking theoretically, for the sake of understanding what the MYSQL Instruction set Literally does when i enter it.  sort of like , when you start using Windows cmd.exe  and you enter {mkdir hello} and have it side by side with a GUI and then watch the folder appear and then type   rmdir hello  and watch it delete,  i like understanding how things work, But i will certainly take your advise on board,  THANKYOU  be cool